# Utilise common entity classes across different JAX-WS web services

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have a few JAX-WS web services hosted on the same server. They use the same entity objects, but when the web services are consumed by a client, the reflected entity objects are always different between the web services.

How do I force all the clients to identify the entity objects to be of the same data type across multiple web services?

i.e.

webservice.Student class for web service StudentAdministration
and
webservice.Student class for web service ClassAdministration

are both different objects in the consumer's point of view. How do I change my web service to expose the webservice.Student class to let the consumer know that both are the same entity types, even though they are exposed from different web services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the common entities in a single XML schema as described here:

https://javaee.github.io/metro/doc/user-guide/ch03.html#compiling-multiple-wsdls-that-share-a-common-schema

Comment: In that case, is it possible to do anything on the web service side that can cause the consumer's generated classes to be the same across the number of web services?

I thought that the last post in http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=28673 is relevant to what I want to do, but I don't really understand how I'm going to include the 2 files the author states inside ant

Comment: The way this should work is the the WSDL for each service should reference the same schema.  When you generate the stubs for each service (from the WSDL) identical classes will be generated based on the common schema.  These identical classes can then be shared by each consumer.  Does that make sense or have I missed something?

Comment: What if the WSDL is automatically being generated by JAX-WS based on the endpoint classes? We have a similiar situation in which we have multiple endpoints which share common entities. wsimport puts each set of classes (for each endpoint) in a separate package, however we'd like the common classes to be in a different 'common' package.

Comment: Here is an updated link for [Compiling multiple WSDLs that share a common schema](https://javaee.github.io/metro/doc/user-guide/ch03.html#compiling-multiple-wsdls-that-share-a-common-schema).